# Is it possible to tweak your computer's random function?

Tags: c, linux, random, linux-kernel, libc

In order to cheat the game 2048 for fun, does anyone know how to change the random implementation on Windows or Linux?
On a linux kernel, I guess that you reimplement the rand function simply like this:

```
double rand() {
  return 0.0;
}
```

then rebuild your kernel.

But no idea on Windows.

I would appreciate any help on it.

Comment: Isn't 2048 written in JavaScript? What does this have to do with C?

Comment: Because your browser's js engine is written in c++ and is based on your os kernel !

Comment: Says who? That's certainly not the case in the Microsoft implementation of JavaScript, or at least it was not when I wrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to beat 2048 simply open your web browser's console while playing the game and type in:

```
Math.random = function() { return 0.0 }
```

In firefox it is ***Tools -> Web developer -> Web console***

In Chromium it is ***Tools -> Javascript console***.

P.S. I had to check if it's not yet April 1st as rebuilding kernel in order to
cheat a web game sounds a bit too extreme

Comment: Yes! Its a simplier way to override random() without getting the system unstable!